# Pass C string to python (ctypes)

Tags: python, c, string, ctypes

I'm trying to pass char * and char ** from my C code to Python via ctypes. Here is my code:

.h

```
int process(unsigned char *line, unsigned char (*word)[128], char *(chunk)[16]);
```

.c file

```
unsigned char line[256];
unsigned char word[266][128];
char chunk[128][16];

fprintf(stdout, " output_value: %d, %s, %s", process(line, word, chunk), word[0], chunk[0]);
```

.py

```
fin = open(filename, encoding='UTF-8')
content = fin.read().splitlines()

_process = _mod.process
_process.argtypes = [ POINTER(c_ubyte), POINTER(c_char_p), POINTER(c_char_p) ]
_process.restype = c_int

string_org = ''.join(map(str, content)).encode("UTF-8")
line = (c_ubyte * len(string_org)).from_buffer_copy(string_org)

word = (c_char_p)()
chunk = (c_char_p)()

print("output_value: %d %s %s" %(process(line, word, chunk), word[0], chunk[0]))
```

Result:

```
TypeError: 'c_char_p' object is not subscriptable --> print("output_value: %d %s %s" %(process(line, word, chunk), word[0], chunk[0]))
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

What causes this problem?

Is it related to some memory management or just it is wrong approach of getting C string?

Can someone answer my question. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

`word = c_char_p()` creates an instance of a pointer equivalent to `char* word = 0` in C.  It is a null pointer so calling your `process` function dereferences a null pointer and crashes.

`POINTER(c_char_p)` is a type equivalent to `char**` in C, which isn't in your function signature.

Below is functioning DLL code to write to the types you want, but I am assuming `char *(chunk)[16]` was a typo and you really wanted `char (*chunk)[16]`:

**test.c**

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

__declspec(dllexport)
int process(char *line, char (*word)[128], char (*chunk)[16]) {
    printf("%s\n",line);
    strcpy_s(word[0],128,"hello");
    strcpy_s(word[1],128,"world");
    strcpy_s(chunk[0],16,"one");
    strcpy_s(chunk[1],16,"two");
    return 2;
}
```

**test.py**

```py
from ctypes import *

# type declarations
dll = CDLL('./test')
dll.process.argtypes = c_char_p,POINTER(c_char * 128),POINTER(c_char * 16)
dll.process.restype = c_int

word = (c_char * 128 * 2)()   # equivalent to C char word[2][128]
chunk = (c_char * 16 * 2)()   # equivalent to C char chunk[2][16]

ret = dll.process(b"some line", word, chunk)
print(f'{ret} {word[0].value} {word[1].value} {chunk[0].value} {chunk[1].value}')
```

Output:

```
some line
2 b'hello' b'world' b'one' b'two'
```

For reading your file, if I am intepreting your code correctly you want to read the whole file in and remove newlines to make one long line.  Since the file was originally expected to be UTF-8 you can skip the decode/encode and simply do:

```
with open(filename,'rb') as f:
    line = f.read().replace(b'\n',b' ')
```